# Soft keyboard doesn't hide

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

My app has one activity with three fragments. There is listview in first (Frg1) and third(Frg3) fragments. Second fragment(Frg2) has one editText. 
Soft keyboard auto shown when i start Frg2. It's right. 
I try Frg2.onPause this code

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    editText.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            editText.clearFocus();
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
}
```

**When i start Frg1 or Frg2 after Frg3 soft keyboard hides but after render Frg1/Frg2 keyboard shows again.**

Code sample(in Frg3):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    editText.requestFocus();
}
```

and

```
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            editText.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

In Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ContentActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
```

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I found the solution

#### 1. Delete

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            editText.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

#### 2. Add

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    editText.requestFocus();
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
}
```

#### and

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    View v = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if(v != null) {
        v.clearFocus();
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    editText.clearFocus();
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: you have asked for focus on your edittext  using editText.requestFocus();.This causes the edittext to gain focus and the soft keyboard pops up.Either remove this or hide the soft keyboard programatically.

Comment: if i don't add this code `editText.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
                }
            });` keyboard does not auto show

Comment: what exactly is the flow and what you want to achive.Please elaborate little more

Comment: Thanks a lot! You help me with `editText.requestFocus();`

Comment: is your problem solved? if it helped then i shall put my comment as answer so u may accept.

Comment: Yes, i solved. I started to think about changing the focus in the field and gradually found a solution. I added a solution in question.

Comment: better add it as answer so others may find it useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

#### 1. Delete

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

#### 2. Add

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    editText.requestFocus();
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
 }
```

#### 3. Add

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    View v = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if(v != null) {
        v.clearFocus();
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    editText.clearFocus();
}
```

Thanks all!